# Assigning MPD audio output to jack and other applications to HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, output

Is there a solution to set the MPD audio output to local/jack and other applications audio output to HDMI?

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, Raspbian with Retropie and I want to set Retropie audio output to the HDMI and MPD audio output to the jack audio output in the same time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

the output for mpd is configured in `/etc/mpd.conf` as explained for example [here](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/config_audio_outputs.html).

so without changing anything else in the system, the default output for other apps should be furthermore hdmi.

further information about using multiple audio output can be found [here](http://alsa.opensrc.org/MultipleCards).